# Trouble installing SRILM on MacOS

Tags: macos, installation, srilm

I'm trying to install SRLIM on my Mac running El Capitan. The installation seems to be going along but in the test phase it throws a bunch of errors about not finding files, for example:

> ./File.cc:23:10: fatal error: 'Array.cc' file not found /#include
>   "Array.cc"

I've checked, and all of the files are there. Something else must be going wrong but I can't figure out what it is.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What version of `srilm` are you trying to install?

Comment: On my Mac OS X El Capitan I successfully installed srilm 1.7.1. `make test` ran to completion without any errors. I followed [these instructions](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~wooters/SRILM/3%20Install(07F18266).html). I did a `make World` *not* `make MACHINE_TYPE=... World`. I have Xcode 7.0.1. Did you do anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: I'm trying to install 1.7.1. as well. I followed the same instructions as you did (from Wooter at ICSI), and used make World. I also have Xcode 7.0.1. I tried to upgrade my gcc using homebrew, but that didn't seem to work. So I'm still running gcc version 4.2.1. Maybe that's why it is not finding c/c++ files that I know to exist.